# Textboxes value auto change

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

When I change any of the rest of the input boxes equal to the total money distributed to others.
Such as:

```
total: 50
input1: 20
input2: 15
input3: 15
```

be

Javascript solutions?
I wanted to do the following: change the entered value of the input boxes, one value out of the total value, the value of the share out the other input boxes

Comment: Sense, your post makes none. Please try to write your question down more clearly, and use the appropriate tags.

Comment: I didnt understand your question clearly. Do you want the solution in c# or javascript. I understand the roblem is that when one of the textboxes value changes, you want that to reflect in others.

Comment: it is impossible to understand what you are trying to do. take some time and frame your question nicely.

Comment: Give us some sample code, because it's impossible to answer a question described like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

attach a [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event to the text box whose value you want to monitor like

```
$("#asd").change(function(){

 $(".asd").val($(this).val());
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qSeCk/) (write in the first textbox)

or you can use `keyup`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qSeCk/2/)

Comment: +1 for attempting to answer even though the question is poorly written. Nice to see people still trying to help.

Comment: I wanted to do the following: change the entered value of the input boxes, one value out of the total value, the value of the share out the other input boxes

Answer (score 0):

The question is not enough clear, but as far as I understand you want to calculate the value of one textbox on change of another

If yes, you can use [.change() method](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the "change" method as suggested. The tricky part, however, is to write a handler, that reacts to this event.

You will need this while writing your javascript function:

- you need some array, that will contain IDs of relevant textboxes
- you need to know, which textbox triggered the event, so that you
  don't change its value as well

When you know these things, you can just modify the values in other textboxes the way you need.

Hope this helps at least bit. Can't help more, unless you form your question better.

Comment: I wanted to do the following: change the entered value of the input boxes, one value out of the total value, the value of the share out the other input boxes

Comment: What have you tried so far? Maybe it would be more descriptive than your English skills, no offense meant.